# Cosa significa l'espressione "si fa presto a dire"?

Tags: meaning

Che cosa significa l'espressione "si fa presto a dire"? Per esempio: “Si fa presto a dire prosecco” o “si fa presto a dire casa”.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

L'espressione “Si fa presto a dire X” significa che il concetto X è più ricco e magari più negativo di quello che potrebbe sembrare a prima vista, insinuando che se ne parli con troppa leggerezza.

Adesso è quasi un cliché usato nelle pubblicità o nei titoli di giornali, ma è presente nella lingua italiana da quel dì. [Lo menzionano Tommaseo e Bellini](https://books.google.it/books?id=ot45nf9TOdYC&dq=%22si%20fa%20presto%20a%20dire%22&pg=PA653#v=onepage&q=%22si%20fa%20presto%20a%20dire%22&f=false) nel loro *Dizionario della lingua italiana* del 1869, e cercando con Google Books se ne trovano vari esempi d'annata (anche se, a quel che pare, un tempo era più frequente l'uso seguito da una subordinata: “si fa presto a dire che ...”). Mi piace ricordare in particolare *Si fa presto a dire fame*, il libro autobiografico del 1954 in cui [Piero Caleffi](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piero_Caleffi) ricordò le sue esperienze come internato a Mauthausen.